# How to put value into listview where column header is define

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with my project I need to put value into listview where column header is define.

I have table name tbl_writtenactivity with 2 field name (Id,type)

I have table name tbl_writtenwork with a fielname rawscore

In my Project i have listview and i call the type in tbl_writtenactivity to place in the column header in my listview name lsvscore

This is my class to call the type into lsvscore Code:

```
Public Sub setListColumnHeader(ByVal lsv As ListView, ByVal sec As String)
        lsv.Columns.Clear()
        Dim sql As String = "Select type from tbl_writtenactivity w inner join tbl_highscore h on w.id = h.writtenactivityId " & _
                            "inner join tbl_section se on h.sectionID = se.id where se.section ='" & sec & "'"
        GLOBAL_VARS.d.execute(sql)
        If GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader.HasRows Then
            While GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader.Read()
                With lsv
                    .Columns.Add(GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader("type").ToString(), 110, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                End With
            End While
        End If
        GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader.Close()
    End Sub
```

Now the problem is, only the last loop from my database are been place into my listview, the two fields are connected with inner join and use the columnheader as my where clause in my sql script #

This is my code on calling the value rawscore and place into the listview item:

```
Public Sub contentlistview(ByVal lsv As ListView, ByVal activity As String)
        lsv.Items.Clear()
        Dim sql As String = "select w.id,w.rawscore from tbl_writtenwork w inner join tbl_highscore h on w.possibleScoreId_Written = h.id inner join tbl_writtenactivity wr on h.writtenactivityId = wr.id where wr.type = '" & activity & "'"
    GLOBAL_VARS.d.execute(sql)
    If GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader.HasRows Then
        While GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader.Read
            With lsv
                .Items.Add(GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader("rawscore").ToString)
            End With
        End While

    End If
    GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader.Close()

End Sub
```

Please Help: Sorry i dont know how to put pictures from my desktop

Comment: The ListView only *looks like* it has columns.  Add SubItems to your ListView items for them to show in the control.  If you filled a datatable, you could use a DGV more easily:  `myDGV.DataSource = myDT`

Comment: i tried to add Subitems into it but it doesn`t work, look like this:
items(i).subitems.add(GLOBAL_VARS.d.reader("rawscore").ToString)

i add this one:
Dim i as Integer = lsv.items.count